# I need help making a power bank

Tags: power-supply

This is the crude schematic I made in paint: [http://imgur.com/OAdrVsM](https://imgur.com/OAdrVsM)

I want to know whether this would be sufficient to power a 12v case fan.

Parts:

Batteries *3

Adafruit Industries Lithium Ion Polymer Battery - 3.7v 2500mAh

Description:
The batteries come pre-attached with a genuine 2-pin JST-PH connector as shown and include the necessary protection circuitry. Because they have a genuine JST connector, not a knock-off, the cable wont snag or get stuck in a matching JST jack, they click in and out smoothly.

Fan *1

Kingwin 140mm Advance Series Bearing Case Fan

Description:

Microcenter: 
Model CF-014LB 140 x 140 x 25 mm long life bearing case fan RPM,1000, dBA,23 Bearing type, Long life bearing Special high profile fan blades for maximum air flow Provide excellent ventilation for your PC cases Design for up to 100,000 hrs life expectancy High performance High reliability 3 Pin/4 Pin Connector

Kingwin:
Model:  CF-014LB
Product Type:   Fan
Fan Dimension:  140 x 140 x 25 mm
Fan Speed:  1000 RPM
Bearing Type:   Long life bearing
Noise Level:    23 dB(A)
Air Flow:   58 CFM
Rated Voltage:  DC 12 V
Operational Voltage:    10.8 – 13.3 V
Wattage:    0.96 W
Weight: 0.42 lbs/ pc

*NOTE: The 3 Pin/4 Pin Connector is going to be snipped off and replaced with a JST-PH Connector

P.S. I meant JST-PH not JST-SM(In The Schematic)

Comment: How do you plan to charge these batteries? This is where most mistakes are made when using multiple Li-ion batteries.

Comment: Please use the schematic editor in the question edit window to create your schematic. For the times that you want to import a schematic that you have exported from other software, please include the image in the question instead of through a link.

Comment: The short answer is yes, provided you remove the batteries and charge separately as normal.

Comment: @Sparky256 Im using the adafruit battery charger with adafruit li-ions.

Comment: Please convert the image to a png, then upload it to imgur

Answer (score 1):

I can't stress this enough: **you have to remove the batteries and charge them separately**. This is critical!

---

You said you have three:

> Lithium Ion Polymer Battery - 3.7v 2500mAh

And a fan that runs on:

> DC 12 V Operational Voltage: 10.8 – 13.3 V Wattage: 0.96 W

So lets see, 3 * 3.7v = 11.1v, and 10.8v < 11.1v < 13.3v, maybe it will work so far... at least the voltage should be ok *at full charge*.

About that wattage now, 0.96w / 11.1v = ~86.5mA, pretty modest so I'd hope your batteries can push that. Seems like it could work.

Consider this though: 2500mAh / ~86.5mA = ~28.9h, so in the *totally unrealistic* very best case, it could last a day. These batteries *really* ***hate*** being drained fully. You need to obtain the discharge curve for your batteries to have an idea how long you can run it before the batteries take damage.

Comment: What about a 5v USB charger?

Comment: @Zivicium - Listen to him! You must disconnect the batteries and charge them separately. Do not think you can get around this. Don't even think about it.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I know, im not blind.